# Open SSH client from FileZilla

Tags: windows-7, ssh, filezilla

When connected to a SFTP server in FileZilla, is there any easy way to open an SSH client connected to the server from FileZilla?

Like we can do on WinSCP:

[image]

I use the latest version of FileZilla in Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No FileZilla does not have the functionality or anything similar.

Though it's an open source project, so you may add the function, if you need it.